# Python. Will TWO condition checked, If `ONE == True`?

Tags: python

Question about mecanism of a check conditions. `if ONE or TWO:`
Will TWO condition checked, If `ONE == True`? Where can I read about this?

Comment: Have you considered that he could not know the meaning of the word *short-circuiting*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python this is called *short-circuiting*. Logical expressions are evaluated left to right (taking into account brackets) and execution stops as soon as it is clear what the logical answer will be.

Try this code in the interactive console:

```
>>> def one():
...     print "one called"
...     return True

>>> def two():
...     print "two called"
...     return True

>>> one() or two()
```

The response will be:

```
one called
True
```

The same thing happens with `and` (if the first argument is False, the 2nd argument is never evaluated).

Answer (score 2):

This is called *short-circuiting*, and Python does support it. You can read an explanation in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Python [short-circuits](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) the evaluation of Boolean expressions.